# Cookies not set. Using AWS lambda, AWS API gateway(HTTP not REST) and vercel

Tags: amazon-web-services, next.js, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am sending `Set-Cookies` header but the browser is not setting the cookies.

backend code(Lambda):

```
import { verifyToken, createToken } from "/opt/auth.mjs";
import { DynamoDBClient } from "@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb";
import {
    DynamoDBDocumentClient,
    PutCommand,
    GetCommand,
    DeleteCommand,
    UpdateCommand,
} from "@aws-sdk/lib-dynamodb";

const client = new DynamoDBClient({});
const dynamo = DynamoDBDocumentClient.from(client);
export const handler = async (event) => {
    let body= "hello World"
    let statusCode = 200;
    const multiValueHeaders = {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Set-Cookie": [
            'isLoggedin=true',
            ],
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': '*'
    };
    return {
        body,
        multiValueHeaders,
        statusCode,
    };
};
```

Frontend fetch (Next.js hosted on Vercel):

```
const response = await fetch(url, {
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
        });
```

What I have tried:

- multivalueheaders(not ever receiving headers as far as the chrome webtools can shows)
- normal headers(sends the header but the browswer doesn't save it)